# Javascript: add a text into text area

Tags: javascript, load, textarea

I would like to load a text into text area, when clicked in a map area.
When I click in the second area, I would like to add another (different) text

How can I make this happen?

http://jsfiddle.net/CQvKJ/

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't really matter. WYSIWYG editors have buttons which add text to user input aswell. This is foor supporting the user in most cases. Take a look at the CKEditor for example. It uses a textarea, too.

Comment: because the content will be send into the form :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Mootools, so I did this in JS only without framework.
This may not be a *good* solution, but this is basically what you want to do, no matter how you append the text.

#### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/CQvKJ/2/

#### Updated JS

```
function funzione1() {
    // alert("add text : 1.");
    var e = document.getElementById('my_text');
    e.value += "1";
}

function funzione2() {
    // alert("add text: 2");
    var e = document.getElementById('my_text');
    e.value += "2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Identify the `<textarea>` by id.
2. Retrieve the element in the click handlers.
3. Set the element's value to the text you want to show up.

[Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/Hpab3/).

Comment: Oh, I understood _add another different text_ as append. Good, now we have both solutions covered! :)